# Retorno de vetor e matriz de uma função no c!

Tags: c

O problema que eu estou tendo é que o meu ponteiro serieinversa fica todo nulo, sendo que o resto do código roda de boa, eu realmente não encontro qual é o problema!
Se alguem poder me ajudar eu agradeço desde já!!Obs.: Tem algumas blibiotecas a mais para a utilização em outros códigos que n tem nenhuma ligação com esse em questão!

main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "repository.h"

int main()
{
    int *serieoriginal;
    int *serieinversa;
    unsigned int i, j;
    serieoriginal = (int*) calloc(12, sizeof(int));
    serieinversa = (int*) calloc(12, sizeof(int));

    printf("Bem vindo ao modo de musica Dodecafonico!\n\n");

    printf("Digite os valores da serie!\n");
    Sleep(300);
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("  %d valor: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &serieoriginal[i]);
    }

    *serieinversa = SeInv(serieoriginal);

    printf("\nSerie original: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("%d ", serieoriginal[i]);
    }
    printf("\nSerie inversa: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("%d ", serieinversa[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

blibioteca repository.h:

```
#ifndef REPOSITORY_H_
#define REPOSITORY_H_

int* SeInv(int* s);

#endif
```

repository.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

int* SeInv(int *s)
{
    int P[12]/*serie transposta*/, *R[12]/*serie retrogradada*/;
    int i, k, aux;

    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
    k = 5;//rand()%12;
    printf("\n K: %d\n", k);
    printf("\nSerie: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("%d ", s[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        aux = s[i];
        aux = (aux + k)%12;
        P[i] = aux;
    }
    printf("\nP: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("%d ", P[i]);
    }
    k = 0;
    for (i = 12; i > 0; i--) {
        R[k] = P[i-1];
        k++;
    }
    printf("\nR: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("%d ", R[i]);
    }
    return (*R);
}
```

Comment: Por que as tags c++ e c#?

Comment: Jovem, C, C++ e C# **não são** a mesma coisa.

Comment: coloquei apenas para ter uma gama maior de pessoas que poderiam me ajudar!

Answer (score 1):

Consertei o retorno do método, quanto a ordem dos valores, não sei se deve retornar o exatamente o inverso da original, ou alguma ordem em seus cálculos.

Primeiramente a no arquivo `main.c` a linha:

```
serieinversa = (int*) calloc(12, sizeof(int));
```

Não tem a necessidade de alocar um tamanho para o ponteiro, pois ele recebera um endereço de um método mais para frente. Nesse caso o ideal é:

```
serieinversa = NULL;
```

---

Na linha:

```
*serieinversa = SeInv(serieoriginal);
```

O método `SeInv` retorna um ponteiro de inteiros, a sua variável `serieinversa` já é um ponteiro de inteiros, no caso do código, você está tentando armazenar o endereço retornado dentro de outros endereço. O correto seria.

```
serieinversa = SeInv(serieoriginal);
```

---

No arquivo repository.c, alinha:

```
int P[12]/*serie transposta*/, *R[12]/*serie retrogradada*/;
```

Esta declarando um ponteiro de um vetor de 12 posições `*R[12]`, o ideal é, usar apenas vetor ou apenas ponteiro, no caso do trecho do código, diria que está parecendo mais uma matriz, mudei para:

```
int P[12]/*serie transposta*/;
int *R = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*12);
```

Como R é o sei retorna, deve ser um ponteiro para não ter incompatibilidade com seu método e variável que irá recebê-la.

---

E por fim o retorno de `SeInv`:

```
return (*R);
```

Você está retornando o vetor que estava em `R`, mas os valores não estão dentro do vetor dentro de `R`, e sim em `R`. Por isso que deve retornar apenas o `R`:

```
return R;
```

---

Sugiro dar uma revisado no calculo de inversão para ver se está realmente correto.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, era realmente a alocação do ponteiro R na função SeIvn() que estava ocasionando o problema, e referante ao calculo de inversão, não é apenas uma inversão, tem mais coisa, mas meu problema era só o retorno da função msm, muito obrigado!

Comment: @GuilhermeGehlen, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, você pode marcar o "V" do lado da resposta para indicar que está resolvido